# Where is the mistake in coding permutation test in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics, permutation, python-itertools

I'm using Python 3.4.1 and try to rebuilt a permutation test with *itertools*.

Popular code for this, found over [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutation_test#Python) is this:

```
from itertools import combinations as comb

def permutationTest(a, b):
    ab = a + b
    Tobs = sum(a)
    under = 0
    for count, perm in enumerate(comb(ab, len(a)), 1):
        if sum(perm) <= Tobs:
            under += 1
    return under * 100. / count

treatmentGroup = [9.1, 10.3, 11.0, 11.5, 11.9]
controlGroup   = [8.1, 8.4, 9.2, 9.4]
under = permutationTest(treatmentGroup, controlGroup)

averageTreatment = sum(treatmentGroup) / float(len(treatmentGroup))
averageControl = sum(controlGroup) / float(len(controlGroup))
print("under=%.2f%%, over=%.2f%%" % (under, 100. - under))
print ('The average of threatment group is', averageTreatment)
print ('The average of control group is', averageControl)
```

As you see, there the two (treatment and control) groups defined as usual. I also took an example there from a university I found over [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/~dahinden/Kurs/Permutationstest/Permutationstests%20f%C3%BCr%20das%20Zwei.docx). **My problem now**: As you see, the results are different.

Does anyone know, where the mistake is located? (I guess it's in the Python script...)

Thanks for advice!

Comment: @xfer can you please tell where actually the diffrence? show the output that you want.

Comment: As far as I see it, Python print out is under=98.41%, over=1.59%. According to the document I also linked it should be 2,38%.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have lies in the `<=`. In the document you linked,  they add it to over if t >= 1.98, so it should be added to under only for values t < 1.98, or `sum(perm) < Tobs`.